# How to make accounting balance report?

Tags: sql, oracle-apex-19.2

I'm new to Oracle apex and SQL. I am developing an Oracle app for accounting. My table `ga_voucher` contains the following columns with values like:

```
VNO | DBIT CODE | AMOUNT | CREDIT CODE  |  VDATE       | NARRATION
01      121005     40000       331001    09/07/2021    ABCD
02      331002    50000        121005    09/07/2021
```

I want to generate report with unique account code balance (debit total of a code - credit total) like:

```
Account CODE | DEBIT TOTAL|CREDIT TOTAL | BALANCE
331002           50000    | 40000       |  10000
```

What is the SQL query for the report? Please help me.

Comment: Please explain the logic for the result set.  How are all these assigned to `331002`?

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure the `331001` in the first row should really be `331002`.  If so, I *think* you want to unpivot the data and aggregate:

```
select x.account_code, sum(x.debit) as debit, sum(x.credit) as credit,
       sum(x.debit - x.credit) as balance\
from ga_voucher v cross join lateral
     (select v.debit_code as account_code, v.amount as debit, 0 as credit from dual union all
      select v.credit_code, 0, v.amount from dual
     ) x
group by x.account_code;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. But it is not working for me. Its shows ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! ORA-06550: line 1, column 8: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

Comment: @Kamruzzaman . . . Ooops, I left out the `group by`.